# If I put down a draw 4 card and call uno out, can another player place a draw 4 ontop?

Tags: uno

My last card was a wild draw 4, I knew my friend had one but I had to put it down. I called uno out and he put his draw 4 ontop of mine. Can he do that?

Answer (score 2):

Per [Uno Rules](https://www.unorules.com), `Once a player has no cards remaining, the game round is over, points are scored, and the game begins over again.`
So, there's no placement once you are out, the round is over.